# Undefined State Reselect Js

Tags: javascript, state, reselect

I am getting the following error: `substate is undefined`. However, I am not sure why `substate` would be undefined in my selector. Could someone please help me figure out what might be going wrong?

Selector:

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

/**
 * Direct selector to the organization state domain
 */
const selectOrganizationDomain = () => (state) => state.get('organization');

/**
 * Other specific selectors
 */


/**
 * Default selector used by organization
 */

const selectOrganization = () => createSelector(
  selectOrganizationDomain(),
  (substate) => substate.toJS()
);

const selectChanges = () => createSelector(
  selectOrganization(),
  (substate) => substate.get('changes')
)

export default selectOrganization;
export {
  selectOrganizationDomain,
  selectChanges
};
```

Comment: Going by the docs, I'm guessing you should pass selectOrganization into createSelector instead of calling it and passing the result of that.

Answer (score 1):

Your `selectOrganizationDomain` should be a function that returns `.get('organization')` on the state:

```
const selectOrganizationDomain = state => state.get('organization');
```

Your composed selectors should be the result of the invocation of `createSelector`, with the other selector functions passed in as arguments to `createSelector`:

```
const selectOrganization = createSelector(
  selectOrganizationDomain,
  substate => substate.toJS()
);

const selectChanges = createSelector(
  selectOrganization,
  substate => substate.get('changes')
);
```

Comment: can you post the code that consumes these selectors? if your `state` is undefined, that's most likely that root of your problems

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `.toJS()` in `selectOrganization`. I suppose `organization` in your state tree is **immutable**. It transforms your immutable object into a regualr JS object. For a regular object the `get` function is not defined.

Just get rid of `selectOrganization` and try `selectChanges` as:

```
const selectChanges = () => createSelector(
  selectOrganizationDomain(),
  (substate) => substate.get('changes')
)
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your state tree as seen when using redux dev tools?

Comment: I would but due to the error, the page that uses the selector doesn't load

Comment: Then please console.log your state in `selectOrganizationDomain`, i.e. `const selectOrganizationDomain = () => (state) => { console.log('organization', state.get('organization')); return state.get('organization'); }` Is organization defined?

Answer (score 1):

I think createSelector is expecting you to pass a selctor for the first argument, not the result of calling a selector:

```
const selectChanges = () => createSelector(
  selectOrganization, // no ()
  (substate) => substate.get('changes')
)
```

Comment: I recieved a new error: `substate.get is not a function`

Comment: @Turtle getting somewhere at least :)  Log substate to the console and see what the heck it is.

Comment: I actually just found the issue, but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. In my routes.js, I forgot to inject my reducer/other modules. This was fixed with the following:

```
{
      path: '/org',
      name: 'organization',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        const importModules = Promise.all([
          System.import('containers/Organization/reducer'),
          System.import('containers/Organization/sagas'),
          System.import('containers/Organization'),
        ]);

        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

        importModules.then(([reducer, sagas, component]) => {
          injectReducer('organization', reducer.default);
          injectSagas(sagas.default);
          renderRoute(component);
        });

        importModules.catch(errorLoading);
      },
    },
```